# Specify scale in a ABS function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Is it possible to specify scale in a ABS function from a decimal ?

```
= ABS(([Accounting].salary+ABS([Accounting].expenses))/2)
```

As of right now everything works correctly but there is a problem with results when the number has only 1 number after the decimal point:

```
100.12 - All ok
230.1 - Not ok, it should be 230.10
```

I want the outcome to always have two numbers after the decimal point.

The query has to work on both MS SQL Server and Oracle. I can specify the query for each db manually.

Comment: Which database you're working on? Oracle/SQL Server/Sybase/MySQL....?

Comment: CAST(value AS  decimal(n,2)) instead, to always get 2 decimals.

Comment: The query has to work on both MSSQL and Oracle, I can specify the query for each db manually

Comment: `ABS([Accounting].expenses)` IS positive, `[Accounting].salary` must be positive (otherwise I wouldn't work for you..), what's the point of the surrounding ABS?

Comment: As odd as it may seem the expenses are all negative

Comment: There is no way `[Accounting].expenses` is going to work in Oracle - even if you do find  a function that works for both DBMS. That is non-standard SQL because  `[..]` is invalid in an SQL identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Just change code:

```
= ABS(([Accounting].salary+ABS([Accounting].expenses))/2)
```

By the following:

```
= CAST(ABS(([Accounting].salary+ABS([Accounting].expenses))/2) AS DECIMAL(18 /*set your format here instead of 18*/,2))
```

I've just checked it in code:

```
SELECT CAST(230.1 AS DECIMAL(18 /*set your format here instead of 18*/, 2))
```

And all works fine

In fact, it's just a question of representation of your numbers in the UI for the user. You can convert your number to the string with using to_char () with the format specified. But it is better to define the output format on the front-end

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is more a user interface issue than a SQL issue.

```
230.1 - Not ok, it should be 230.10
```

Seriously, that's both the same number.

In Oracle you can convert a number into a string in order to present it to an end user.

```
select to_char(234.1,'$9,999.99') from dual
 $234.10
```

Have a look at format models in the Oracle documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm